# R installing older versions of packages

Tags: r

R installs older versions of packages. I am trying to get the most recent. Two examples are the radsafer package (my own) and the MASS package (selected because it's a recent update). Other users are able to get radsafer version 2.2.8, but I keep getting 2.2.6. I get MASS 7.3-58.4 rather than 7.3-60.

I'm just baffled and don't know what else to try.

My session info:

R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0 tools_4.3.0

Comment: Not all CRAN mirrors are up to date.  Which one are you using?

Comment: The other possibility is that the source package is up to date, but the binary build is not.  You are on Windows so installs default to the binary build.

Comment: I've tried switching around on the mirrors to see if that's the problem and have even checked those mirrors and found them up to date. But now I may have a new clue. For some reason, I get diverted to https://cran.microsoft.com/bin/windows/contrib/ and that is not up to date.

Comment: @user2554330 But the MASS version they claim to get isn't the one preceding the most recent one. So, binaries not having been compiled yet is unlikely to be the cause because then they should get MASS 7.3-59.

Comment: MASS 7.3-58.2 is also the most recent here: https://cran.microsoft.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/ So, I guess I should edit the question to why am I diverted.

Comment: How exactly are you installing the package? What does `options("repos")` return?

Comment: @MrFlick It returns $repos
                         CRAN 
"https://cran.microsoft.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE

Comment: Note that the Microsoft CRAN repo will be retired soon: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/microsoft-r-application-network-retirement/ba-p/3707161. If you browse that repo you see that that you are getting the most recent versions that are available there. You users are probably using the "standard" CRAN mirrors which has newer version. To set a different mirror, use `chooseCRANmirror()` and choose the first "0-Cloud [https]" option.

Comment: @MrFlick That has to be the right answer and I guess my problem has to be addressed with my IT / Computer Security team, because I get Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'SSL connect error'